# Comparing two arrays in parse query

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server, parse-javascript-sdk

How do we find if any element of an array is part of another array in a query?

`var followers = [];  // Array of Parse User pointers
query.howTo("attending", followers); // attending is an array of User Pointers.`

That is, the query should match if any one or more of the elements in `followers` exists in `attending`.

`query.containsAll` matches for all the elements. Is there something like `query.containsSome` ?

Comment: Have you tried using `containedIn`?

Comment: @NatanR. https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Query.html#methods_containedIn 

It is used to compare key with values. I need to compare array with array.

Comment: Isn't it better in this case using a relation instead of an array of pointers? I think you'll have more flexibility, besides the fact that you can add the relationship in both "sides". Ex.: https://www.parse.com/questions/inverse-relationship-support

Comment: @NatanR. I will give a look into that. But as of now, is comparing arrays supported in a query?

Comment: I think that, for now, you should use compound queries, like I'm going to suggest in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was pretty sure you can query two arrays. Take a look into the docs to check better.

In case it doesn't, you can use compound queries.

For example, generate an array of queries, based on the array of followers. The [forEach] is a better idea in this case, but I'm supposing here a for loop.

`var followers = []; //array of users
var mainQuery = new Parse.Query(YourOtherObject);
//for each one of followers
var orQuery = new Parse.Query(YourOtherObject);
orQuery.equalTo("attending", follower);
mainQuery = Parse.Query.or(mainQuery, orQuery);`

This solution might not be performant if your followers areay is too big. But in any case, I still recommend using relations in this case, as you benefit from the inverse, and can get from the users query, where he is present as attending in the other Object.

Comment: follower array is huge. An average of 250 items. What do you think?

Comment: I think you should use Relations :) They are intended exactly for these cases. Running a JS script you can convert it easily. Otherwise, you can test the performance and see the results by yourself. It might be good or bad.

Comment: Please up vote the question, if it helped you discover something about parse server ;)

Comment: R No luck. Can you provide an example on how to do with relations.